# Progress UIView or Loader UIView with Lightweight coredata migration

Tags: ios, iphone, core-data, swift3

I'm trying to achieve a progress UIView or a simple UIView that says, `Migrating data...` after the Launch screen.

I have read about the custom migration here:
http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2469048&seqNum=5

The issue is migrating data sometimes takes 40-60 seconds or more, so watchdog kills the app, so i wanted to change the UIView so that people may now that whats going on and app should not get frozen on Launch screen.

I wanted to check if the migration is required so i am able do it as:

`if !(managedObjectModel?.isConfiguration(withName: nil, compatibleWithStoreMetadata: metaData))! {
                migrationInProgress = true
            }`

For the progressView, i am unable to check how much is the progress for the migration, Further as this is happening in Core-Data Stack of the app so its the first thing that happens, its here where the NSPersistant Store is registers before we can access any data, so everything is in `init()` initially.

so how do i put my migration(if required) in background thread and change the UIView, before it continues the Migration(Lightweight Migration)?

Comment: Just don’t do the migration during the `didFinishLaunching` method. Let the app launch and display some user interface letting the user no what is happening. Then the system won’t kill your app.

Comment: thank you for your reply, but you have to register the NSPersistantStore before it reaches didFinishLaunching, and if the local scheme doesnot match the new scheme its going to migrate always.